# Failed to find application object 'server' in 'app'

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

I am trying to serve a Dash app using Heroku.  I have 5 files in my app:

.gitignore

```
venv
*.pyc
.DS_Store
.env
```

app.py

```
import os

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

# Read in the data
districts_change = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/thedatasleuth/New-York-Congressional-Districts/blob/master/districts_change.csv?raw=True")

df = districts_change.drop(['TOTAL'], axis=1)

# Get a list of all the districts
districts = districts_change['DISTRICT'].unique()

# Create the app
app = dash.Dash()

# Populate the layout with HTML and graph components
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H2("New York Congressional Districts"),
    html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id="DISTRICT",
                options=[{
                    'label': 'District {}'.format(i),
                    'value': i
                } for i in districts],
                value='All Districts'),
        ],
        style={'width': '25%',
               'display': 'inline-block'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='funnel-graph'),
])


# Add the callbacks to support the interactive componets
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('funnel-graph', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('DISTRICT', 'value')])
def update_graph(Districts):
    if Districts == "All Districts":
        df_plot = df.copy()
    else:
        df_plot = df[df['DISTRICT'] == Districts]

    trace1 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['Year'], y=df_plot [('DEM')], name='DEM')
    trace2 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['Year'], y=df_plot [('REP')], name='REP')
    trace3 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['Year'], y=df_plot [('CON')], name='CON')
    trace4 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['Year'], y=df_plot [('WOR')], name='WOR')
    trace5 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['Year'], y=df_plot [('IND')], name='IND')
    trace6 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['Year'], y=df_plot [('GRE')], name='GRE')
    trace7 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['Year'], y=df_plot [('WEP')], name='WEP')
    trace8 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['Year'], y=df_plot [('REF')], name='REF')
    trace9 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['Year'], y=df_plot [('OTH')], name='OTH')
    trace10 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['Year'], y=df_plot [('BLANK')], name='BLANK')


    return {
        'data': [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4, trace5,
                     trace6, trace7, trace8, trace9, trace10],
        'layout':
        go.Layout(
            title='District {}'.format(Districts),
            barmode='group')
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.server.run(debug=True)
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn app:server
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
dash==0.26.5
dash-core-components==0.29.0
dash-html-components==0.12.0
dash-renderer==0.13.2
plotly==3.2.1
pandas==0.23.1
pandas-datareader==0.6.0
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.6.6
```

I am able to build the app successfully in Heroku, however, I am unable to serve it properly, given this error message:

```
Failed to find application object 'server' in 'app'
```

What server is it talking about?  Usually when I get this error I just add whatever is missing to the requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 10):

I added: `server = app.server` right under `app = dash.Dash()`

Comment: a life saver, fixed the bug