# PyTorch: Load/unpickle only the state dict of a model saved with torch.save

Tags: python, pytorch, pickle

I saved a `nn.Module` model using (logically):

```
model = MyWeirdModel()
model.patched_features = .....
train(model)
torch.save(model, file)
```

Ideally, one would load this model using

```py
model = torch.load(file)
```

However, in my case this doesn't work because Pickle uses the static class definition when un-pickling, so I get `AttributeError: 'MyWeirdModel' object has no attribute 'patched_features'` (this attribute was added to MyWeirdModel at runtime).

I would like to avoid having to re-train the model, so I don't want to change the code for saving, only loading.

```py
# Initialise the model in the same way as before
model = MyWeirdModel()
model.patched_features = .....

state_dict = load_state_dict_only(file) # How does one do this?

model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
```

My understanding is that `torch.save()` saves the model AND the state dict. How do I load only the state dict from the pickled model, such that I can recover the model?

Comment: Hey, did you figure out how to solve it? Have the exact same problem right now

Comment: I never did sadly @Dion I may place a bounty on this.

Comment: what exactly is the `patched_features`?

Comment: Linking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465106/attributeerror-when-reading-a-pickle-file which lists several possible solutions for deserializing a python object when the  "__ main __" module has changed, most notably with custom deserializer. This seems to be the main path forward given that a.) you know not to save object/ function instances in pickles, but b.) you already have done so and need a one-time solution to retrieve this data

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#what-is-a-state-dict),

> only layers with learnable parameters (convolutional layers, linear
> layers, etc.) and registered buffers (batchnorm’s running_mean) have
> entries in the model’s state_dict.

Your `patched_features` is not stored in the model’s state_dict, but you can do so by registering it with `register_parameter` as pointed out by [ptrblck](https://discuss.pytorch.org/u/ptrblck) in this [post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-register-buffer-and-register-parameter-of-nn-module/32723) but it may involve retraining.